# Should I use an index for the following data structure

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table which has a large amount of variable data with the `key` field in particular that has, at the time of writing 14 variants. The structure is as below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `device_data` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `device_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `serialized` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `system` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `key` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_device_data_key` (`device_id`,`key`),
  CONSTRAINT `device_data_device_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`device_id`) REFERENCES `devices` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

The table holds about 80,000 records which demonstrates that there is a large amount of repetition for the value of the `key` field. The problem with this is that if the key value is `key_name_here` and it's repeated 30,000 times, that's 13 bytes for every row * 30,000.

I understand that I could create an enum column but the system itself is very dynamic and subject to change. It's not faesable to create a new enum value for the `key` every time.

So my question here, would it make sense to add an index to the `key` field, in the hope this would reduce overall data consumption and benefit performance or would this simply be detremental to performance?

It's worth adding that in 99% of cases we'd already be filtering down based on the `device_id` column, which makes me suspect this would just be entirely detrimental.

Thanks in advance,
Chris.

Comment: The question should be "What INDEX should I provide for this _query_".  What query or queries will you have?

Comment: "that's 13 bytes for every row * 30,000" - why should indexing that column resolve this?

Comment: @NicoHaase that's what I was asking :) I was wondering whether indexes ultimately resulted in a dictionary/enum style lookup. Based on the responses so far it doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the index costs some storage space, but that alone doesn't hurt performance much. It only takes about 1MB of storage. Unless you're targeting this database to be stored on a mobile device or IoT device, that's pretty insignificant storage-wise.

You already have an index that includes `key`, the one created for the UNIQUE KEY constraint. This index would not help a query that searched for `key` alone, but you said in 99% of cases, you search for `device_id` as well. In that case, the compound index would help reduce the examined rows by both columns. So you don't need to index `key` separately.

The problem might happen if you occasionally run a query searching for `key` without a condition for `device_id`. Then it would do a table-scan and search all 80,000 rows, evaluating them row-by-row against your search condition.

If you're willing to bear the performance drag in these cases, then you can avoid creating an additional index on `key`.

But it's not only important how often you run that queries. It might be that when you run that query, even though it's infrequent, you need it to be optimized better than a table-scan.

Or it could be more important to not have an extra index not for the storage, but because insert/update/delete against this table would have to do three index writes instead of the current two index writes. If you need to optimize for rapid write queries over rapid read queries, that's up to your application needs.

This is something we can't answer for you, it's your judgment call.

Comment: Thanks Bill, great answer. So to clarify I wouldn't get a storage saving from indexing the key field, it just doesn't work like that. I'd actually get a storage increase by creating the index?

Comment: Yes, a new index would use more storage. But storage usually isn't the deciding factor on whether you need an index or not.

Answer (score 1):

(I agree with Bill, and...)

```
device_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
```

Will you have trillions of devices?  If not, use a smaller INT type.

When I see these two statements:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `unique_device_data_key` (device_id, key),
```

It is often better to have just

```
PRIMARY KEY `unique_device_data_key` (device_id, key),
```

because it saves space and avoids a secondary lookup in many cases.

> key value is key_name_here and it's repeated 30,000 times

Only 30K times is not that bad.  The JOIN (at least in this situation) is likely to be worse for performance.

Yes, an `ENUM` with about 40 options would take only 1 byte.  And adding a new 'option' is a very cheap `ALTER TABLE`.  But I don't want to get into the pros and cons of Enums.

If you have queries that do `WHERE Key = '...'` *without* `AND device_id = ...`, then `INDEX(key)` would be useful.

If you need to search `value`, then consider a `FULLTEXT` index on just that column.

For further advice, I need to see the queries.

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer and possibilities. In my instance it'll pretty much always be a case of `SELECT * FROM device_data WHERE device_id = X AND \`key\` = 'example' `. I just wanted to see if an index would offer some kind of deduplication factor saving space. At the moment, for example, I have 14 different key values with 79,075 rows. As you can imagine that's a fair bit of repetition!

Comment: 1-2 megabytes of disk space is not significant to most people _today_.  Is it an important issue _for you_?  Meanwhile, my suggested PK change gets rid of a few megabytes of disk space.

Comment: Thanks, Rick - no it's not particularly important in hindsight and is very little data in reality. We've got a fair few TB to play with so a drop in the ocean really. I'll take a look at the implications of updating the primary key. Thanks!